# Don't have a2ensite on my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, vhosts

I have an ubuntu server running nginx.  I just tried to enable a vhost config and discovered that i don't have the a2ensite command.  I searched with find and whereis and it looks like i just don't have it.  I realise i could hand-roll my own symbolic link from sites-enabled to sites-available but i'd rather use a2ensite/a2dissite to manage this.  How can i install it?

thanks -max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a2ensite` is for Apache2 hence the `a2`. I'm sure you can make a script mimicing its functionality by making it `ln -s` based on the parameter you feed, which it will look in the `sites-available` directory and then invoke `ln` on.

Comment: thanks meder, that makes sense i guess.  i'll just do my own links after all then.  cheers, max

Comment: yo may also use this script https://github.com/perusio/nginx_ensite#readme